# CSS textarea visible overflowed text possible?

Tags: javascript, css

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/TRpxM/

Is it possible to make text fully visible inside textarea?

In real code, css properties getting copied automatically, here is just an example with manually set values.

I'm trying to do text editor, to be seamless with editable div for example.

I'm using line-height to remove vertical empty spaces on some fonts at big font-size.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the line-height and try controlling the font via a p or span attributes. This will give you better control over design. Also consider zero out padding and margin or using a css reset file so you wont have any cross browser issues.

Comment: I guess i'll have to find highest value from font-size, line-height and height and pick it as height of textarea. Nope doesn't work...

Comment: Ok here is solution i was looking for. So i need another wrapper around textarea and calculate -top offset.Any others solutions? http://jsfiddle.net/TRpxM/2/

Answer (score 0):

Just increase the `line-height` to `35px`, as it's fully visible.

Comment: I can't, it will screw up initial design. I have found only one solution. It's to use div -> height:%font-size% but there is another problem vertical-align:middle will gone. If i'll use div -> display:table-cell and vertical-align:middle when width will screw up and i have to set all width via js to force td to be width:100%